# Cython multithread program crashes

Tags: python, multithreading, cython

I'm writing a program which will update certain items in the background, it does that in these steps:

1. Has this item been checked within the last hour, if no:
2. Launch a thread to update it in the background. In the thread:
3. download a web page, and process it.

It does this processing by, in the thread:

1. looking at some variables to do with other program stuff,
2. printing hello to me, to see how far it got,
3. launching a function called download_page,
4. taking the item that download_page returned, and giving it to process page

At the top of both download_page, and process_page, I also put print statements, to see if it gets there.

The problem that I have is thus:
In python, it works fine.
After I cythonise it however, it gets up to the print statement, it carries that out fine, then the next line is to launch download_page with the url as an argument.
The first line of download_page is the print statement.
Accept that actually never happens. It doesn't display an error, doesn't print, its like it just gives up.

I've checked the code using normal python, and it runs fine.
What innicially got me to this was it was crashing with urllib, so I moved over to requests, thinking it might have been that, but then after adding in the print statements, and that one at the top of download_page not even launching...
I'm just not sure what is going wrong.

For reference, I have attached my cython compile file below:

```
import setuptools

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("rss",  ["rss.py"], extra_compile_args=['/openmp']),
#   ... all your modules that need be compiled ...
]

setup(
    name = 'RSS',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

Edit:  Additional code from program:

```
globals.py:

pages={} # this stores loaded pages
pageurl=0 # what url to check
unseen=[] # pages that have been updated and not yet viewed

main file:
import globals as g
import threading
import requests
def updatepage():
 if(threading.activeCount()>10):
  return;  # don't overload CPU's
 print 'Hi, I am working' # did it get this far? In tests, it does.

 thread1=threading.Thread(target = loadpage, args = [g.pageurl])

 thread1.start()

def loadpage(url):
   if(g.pages.has_key(url)==False):
    g.feeds[url]={'feed': 0, 'checklimit': 7200, 'unseen': [], 'last_check': 0}

   oldpage=g.pages[url]

   print 'I am right here, just about to download' # another check statement, which works

   fi=download_page(url)

   # code below this point not related, as it never gets here

def download_page(url):

 print url # it never does that

 r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

 print 'return step' # this never happens

 return r.content
```

Comment: What do you mean with "just gives up"? A crash, as mentioned in the title of the question? Or a hang, with just nothing happening? In the latter case, have you checked whether the program still consumes CPU (endless loop) or does nothing (deadlock)? Have you tried other ways of getting information from the extra threads, like updating a variable that is checked/printed by the main thread? I'm not sure whether print statements are thread safe.

Comment: Cython never releases the GIL unless you tell it to (unlike Python). This can easily cause threads to appear to lock. However with only a vague description of the algorithm this isn't really answerable.

Comment: I've heard a lot about this GIL during my research, but don't entirely understand what it is or how it works, exactly? Here's some sample code that might give you an idea of how the thread works:

Comment: You should edit your sample code into your question - Python is very indent dependent so it doesn't make sense in a comment. You should also read the help on [mre] - your code currently isn't

Comment: Deleted the code from the comment and appended it to the end of the question. Sorry about that. I've never been very good at formatting things here. Hopefully the comments help too.

Comment: In my case I call `rss.updatepages()` and get as far as `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '0': ...`, which I think is the expected outcome. I had to change `g.feeds[url]=...` to `g.pages[url]=...`. This doesn't look like code that's likely to benefit from Cython so it might be easier not to use it. Can't help more given I can't reproduce... sorry

Comment: No worries. I'll keep prodding at the issue. Out of interest, do you know if feedparser, seeing as you mentioned rss feeds, is safe to be used in a cythonised project? And does threads cythonised throw exceptions correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here, but it was thanks to the comments that lead me to try this, and I hope this may help someone who might go on a similar track.

In cython, if an exception is thrown in a thread, it won't show it to you, and will simply stop working.
I through a try and except around the entire function, and in the except part of the code told it to write to a file the words, "You broke it, Dummy."

What would you know? I broke it. Dummy.

Thank you everyone for your help.